# spring data jpa and jpa implementation

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

As we know that, spring data jpa just adds extra layer on jpa provider. Spring community provides some spring data jpa starter example here

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/#initial

I didn't see any jpa provider used in this example, how could that happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot provide jpa
For example, if you want to use Spring and JPA for database access, it is sufficient if you include spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency in your project.